# Silverlight : alternatives for sending a List<T> as an argument for a WCF RIA DomainService method

Tags: wcf, silverlight, service, ria, generic-list

I want to create a DomainService method that receives a List (where T: Entity) kind of an argument, but it seems this cannot be done in Silverlight (Error message : *"operation ... does not conform to the required signature. Parameter types must be an entity or complex type, a collection of complex types, or one of the predefined serializable types."*)

What are the alternatives?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass a T[] array, it should fix it and it is more "proper" as there's no reason to add elements to the list.

Comment: Still gives me the same _"operation ... does not conform to the required signature"_ error.

Answer (score 0):

Serialize the `List<T>` to a `string` in the client and then deserialize it on the server.

I did this with the `DataContractSerializer` and it works great.

WCF RIA Services Contrib also has the ability to Import and Export a collection of entities with added benefits.
http://riaservicescontrib.codeplex.com